# How to pass true or false value in django rest framework serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

here is my serializer code;

```
class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password1 = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(required=True, write_only=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    is_company = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = [
            "email",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "is_company",
            "profile_pic",
            "password1",
            "password2",
        ]

    def validate_email(self, email):
        email = get_adapter().clean_email(email)
        if allauth_settings.UNIQUE_EMAIL:
            if email and email_address_exists(email):
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    ("A user is already registered with this e-mail address.",)
                )
        return email

    def validate_password1(self, password):
        return get_adapter().clean_password(password)

    def validate(self, data):
        if data["password1"] != data["password2"]:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                ("The two password fields didn't match.",)
            )
        return data

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        return {
            "first_name": self.validated_data.get("first_name", ""),
            "last_name": self.validated_data.get("last_name", ""),
            "is_company": self.validated_data.get("is_company", ""),
            "profile_pic": self.validated_data.get("profile_pic", ""),
            "password1": self.validated_data.get("password1", ""),
            "email": self.validated_data.get("email", ""),
        }

    def save(self, request):
        adapter = get_adapter()
        user = adapter.new_user(request)
        self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
        adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
        if self.cleaned_data.get("profile_pic"):
            user.profile_pic = self.cleaned_data.get("profile_pic")
        setup_user_email(request, user, [])
        user.save()
        return user
```

Basically what I am trying to do is, when I make a request with a json format in something like postman;

```
{
    "first_name": firstname,
    "last_name": lastname,
    "email": myemail,
    "password1": password1,
    "password2": password2,
    "is_company": true
}
```

when I pass true to `is_company`, I want that to change `is_company` value to true; but I keep getting false. I have tried using form data, but still get false
I have also tried passing `'true'` or `'True'` but still keep getting false.

Note that I am using django-rest-auth for the authentication, and I am passing `RegisterSerializer` to the django-rest-auth settings in my `settings.py`;

```
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    "REGISTER_SERIALIZER": "users.api.serializer.RegisterSerializer",
}
```

Comment: you can pass your field in save like this:   user.save( is_company = True )

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to solve it is by converting the data that comes from the frontend or postman into a clean data. So instead of something like this;

```
def save(self, request):
        adapter = get_adapter()
        user = adapter.new_user(request)
        self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
        adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
        if self.cleaned_data.get("profile_pic"):
            user.profile_pic = self.cleaned_data.get("profile_pic")
        setup_user_email(request, user, [])
        user.save()
        return user
```

I did this;

```
def save(self, request):
        adapter = get_adapter()
        user = adapter.new_user(request)
        self.cleaned_data = self.get_cleaned_data()
        adapter.save_user(request, user, self)
        if self.cleaned_data.get("profile_pic"):
            user.profile_pic = self.cleaned_data.get("profile_pic")

        # this is new
        if self.cleaned_data.get("is_company"):
            user.is_company = self.cleaned_data.get("is_company")
        setup_user_email(request, user, [])
        user.save()
        return user
```